# How long does iPhone store the original of a cropped video?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, video, video-editing

I tend to take a lot of videos with my iPhone 12 (iOS version 15.6) but usually crop them to only keep the significant parts.

However, I noticed that videos recorded and cropped almost 2 years ago still show the original and it lets me revert changes to restore the original.

So my questions are:

- How long does it keep the original (and potentially unnecessarily clutters up space)
- Is there a way to change this setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple keeps an unmodified original of all photos and videos you take indefinitely. A crop, rotation, transformation operation takes negligible space since it gets applied in real time. Trim operations allow you to save as a new clip and then delete the source video.

That being said, there’s no setting to harvest “original” versions of photos or videos over time. You would need to save a clip or duplicate it in a different app if you need to manage that storage with more granularity.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/edit-photos-and-videos-iphb08064d57/ios

Then delete the original which gets rid of both versions of the file and you keep the crop or edit or cut version only as the new “original”.

> ### Revert an edited photo
>
> After you edit a photo and save your changes, you can revert to the original image.
>
> 1. Open the edited image, tap Edit, then tap Revert.
> 2. Tap Revert to Original.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you happen to have a link to an official documentation of some sorts? This surprises me as this would lead to a lot of unnecessary data.

Comment: I’ll edit to link where Apple describes the functionality. It’s super simple design, you can always revert to original, no exceptions, no time limit. Empirically, you can test this easily, if you edit the oldest photo you have you can revert the changes. How many videos are you editing and do you not get the choice to save the trimmed video as a new clip? Cropping doesn’t make a new file, it just restricts a mask which takes negligible space.

Comment: "Cropping doesn’t make a new file, it just restricts a mask which takes negligible space." was the key, thank you!